# Twitter Bootstrap - input out of bounds when container has padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My container is `span4` and I placed padding/border on it. Everything is fine but inputs are out of bound since they have `span4` class as well. I'm providing my HTML, CSS as well as image that displays the problem.

How can I make sure that inputs are maxed out in width but not out of bounds?

```
<div class="span4 newsletter">
    <h3>Newsletter</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="span4" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" class="span4" />
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="span4" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse pull-right"><i class="icon-envelope icon-white"></i>Subscribe</button>
</div>
```

```
.newsletter {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the class "input-block-level" instead of "span4" on the inputs.